# Is there a single term for "nieces and nephews"?

Tags: single-word-requests, names, kinship-terms, hypernyms, gender-neutral

I find it handy when talking about my sons and daughters I can just say my children.  It's nice to say nieces instead of sibling's daughters. I wonder if there is a similar term for nieces and nephews together? I imagine I could say sibling's kids but I was hoping for a single word.

Comment: @Orbling Hear hear!

Comment: In italian, you have one word (nipote) [for](http://translate.google.com/#en|it|nephew) [both](http://translate.google.com/#en|it|niece), unfortunately the ambiguity doesn't [stop](http://translate.google.com/#en|it|grandson) [there](http://translate.google.com/#en|it|granddaughter)!

Comment: what a good question !

Comment: In some Norwegian dialects you could use "tantebarn" (lit. aunt-children) if you're female. Logically the male equivalent should be "onkelbarn" (uncle-children) but I've never heard it. (Maybe men don't speak that much about children? I've never had the need for a short word for it anyway)

Comment: In Norwegian we also have both gendered and a neutral word for cousins: "fetter" for male cousin, "kusine" for female cousin and "søskenbarn" (lit. sibling-children, somewhat illogical I think) for cousins of any gender.

Comment: My parents' grandchildren . . and my in-laws' grandchildren. (FAIL)

Comment: And in Esperanto there is a prefix ("ge-") meaning both sexes taken together, so, "genevoj" (the "j" marking the plural), in this case.

Comment: In English, the [phrases](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sons+and+daughters%2Cnieces+and+nephews%2Cbrothers+and+sisters%2Chusbands+and+wives&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) "brothers and sisters", "aunts and uncles", "sons and daughters", "nieces and nephews", are very common. I suspect the only people who feel a need for a single-word expression for "nieces and nephews" are ESL speakers whose native language contained this word. (Or maybe native English speakers who want to say "niece or nephew" when they're unsure about somebody's sex.)

Comment: It's a curious lacuna, considering English has: *child(ren), parent, grandparent, grandchild(ren), sibling, cousin, and friend*. None of which specify the gender. In Italian you have *nipoti* for nephews and nieces, or grandchildren, sometimes they can all be clumped together. Italians generally react amazed that English has gender specific words for sibling descendents. *Aunts and uncles* is swiftly dealt with the expression, "gli zii", which makes me curious as to why there is no English equivalent.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

There seems to be no "official" word for "nieces and nephews".

You will find "[**nibling**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nibling)", by analogy with [*sibling*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sibling). (But it is mentioned only in the "[New Words & Slang](http://www3.merriam-webster.com/opendictionary/newword_display_alpha.php?letter=Ni)" section of Merriam-Webster, or in sites like [urbandictionary.com](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=niblings))

In [this Yahoo answers thread](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091219201231AA0TpZD), `KISS = Keep It Simple, Stupid`'s answer also mentions:

- that there is no encompassing word for aunt/uncle either
- that there is no male/female form of cousin.

The article "[There isn't a word for it](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1570791/)" (by Neville Goodman, British Journal of General Practice, 2005) also confirms that there is no word for nephews and nieces, and makes the following (humorous) suggestions:

> The word sibling comes from Old English, and just means related by blood.  I suggest taking the parental ‘p’ to replace the ‘s’, so aunts and uncles are ‘piblings’. Following the pattern, nephews and nieces become ‘niblings’, a nice word that describes what they do to their piblings' bank balances at Christmas and birthdays.

You can find the term used recently in this blog post "[The Christmas Gift that Keeps On Giving](http://solofemininity.blogs.com/posts/2010/12/the-christmas-gift-that-keeps-on-giving.html)", but you can also find it in one of the episodes of an [old 1980 adventure series "The Moomins"](http://www.thechestnut.com/moomins.htm):

[image: Excerpt from Moomin Winter featuring the word "nibling"]

<sup>(from "[Moomin Winter in Moomin Book 5](http://forbiddenplanet.co.uk/blog/2010/moomin-book-5-a-gloriously-surreal-finale/)")</sup>

Comment: +1 purely for the moomins. Can I nominate 'ancles' for aunts and uncles?

Comment: @CJM: you could, except it might be tricky to pronounce it right ('ancles') and still being able to differentiate it from 'uncles'. If the context is not accurate enough, one could believe your are talking about 'uncles' with a funny accent.

Comment: @VonC, @CJM, and ankles :)

Comment: @CJM: How about "auncles" instead?

Comment: +1 Generally probably the only road forward and there are Moomins, anything with Moomins gets voted up out of principle.

Comment: I was joking about 'ancles'...  I think the linked article suggests 'piblings' us a similar logic to 'niblings' (i.e. Parent's sIBLINGS)

Comment: This is Anna, my cousinette from Toledo.

Comment: The Nibling in *The Moomins* isn't a nephew or niece but one of [The Niblings](https://research.wsulibs.wsu.edu:8443/jspui/html/2376/1535/moomin.htm#niblings).

Answer (score -1):

*Nibling* is the most common, but alternatives include *nephling* or *niefling*:

> **nephling:** *(rare)* A nibling
> My dear **neph-ling**: I congratulate you on the attainment of your degree as “Master of Arts.” […] Your affectionate uncle, Cinna Beverley. [[link]](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nephling)
>
> ---
>
> **niefling:** *(rare)* A nibling
> *I come from a very large family (three brothers, three sisters, about as many aunts and uncles, and loads more cousins and **nieflings**) almost all of whom I've fallen out of contact with and honestly don't feel bad about it.* [[link]](https://web.archive.org/web/20150513082638/https://forums.penny-arcade.com/discussion/177288/is-losing-contact-with-your-brother-that-bad)

(Definitions from Wiktionary)