# Word/phrase to unambiguously refer to "aunt, uncle, and cousins"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, hypernyms

Consider this phrase

> Today I toured around the city with *an aunt, uncle and cousins* who came to visit me.

**Is there a shorter word/expression that unambiguously refers to my aunt, uncle and cousins?**

I am aware of [relatives](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/relative), but this is not unambiguous. So, if I say relatives, someone might feel the need to ask for further clarification, for instance, if it was my nuclear family who came to visit me.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dupe.

Comment: I've heard the expression *second-degree relatives* to be an in-between from *immediate family* to *distant relatives*, but I don't think it's specific to *aunts, uncles, and cousins*. For one, grandparents are generally included; secondly, there are no clear cut-offs in terms of closeness of the cousins (first cousin versus second cousin, etc.) before one becomes a *distant relative*.

Comment: Is this a concept represented by a single word or shorter phrase in your native language (that is, are you looking for a translation)? Or are you just curious?

Comment: @Mitch I encountered this in English, so not looking for a translation. It just felt a bit "inefficient" to have to provide such details.

Comment: @luchonacho I can't say for certain that there is absolutely no such word or phrase, but I very much doubt there is one. 'In-laws' captures just parents and siblings of one's spouse, but I can't think of an analogous single word/phrase for blood relatives that are a single or double step away. 'aunts/uncles/cousins' works good enough.

Comment: @Mitch Ok I see. Actually, I cannot think of one in Spanish either (albeit because of male dominance in plural, you can say "tios y primos", slightly shorter, which encompasses aunts, uncles, and cousins of any gender).

Comment: @luchonacho Right...it seems like a reasonably common concept, eg visiting the nuclear family of your aunt. But there are many concepts that don't have a single word or set phrase. I feel like a more common concept would be ones grandparents on one side and their children and grandchildren (but that is with respect to the grandparents). But even that doen't exist in English.

Comment: I often talk about my [**mum's side of the family**](https://books.google.it/books?id=Loa1BgAAQBAJ&pg=PT4&lpg=PT4&dq=%22mum%27s+side+of+the+family%22&source=bl&ots=maO_gwF-F4&sig=aqsn5pIFvX1e7999X69-P9leA2w&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22mum's%20side%20of%20the%20family%22&f=false), she was one of ten children.

Comment: Duplicate https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31033/is-there-a-gender-neutral-word-for-aunts-and-uncles-parents-siblings

Comment: My aunt's immediate family (implying husband and kids)  sufficiently vague in terms of on mom/dads side.  though if the cousins were from a different aunt/uncle this would be incorrect.

Comment: Assuming aunt and uncle are spouses, and the cousins are their children (not necessarily the case), I'd suggest "aunt Alice/Uncle Bob and her/his family", using the aunt or uncle related to you by blood.  Otherwise, I'd just say "some visiting relatives".

Comment: @Scath that is not a duplicate question. That question asks only about one's parent's siblings, not one's cousins too, and also that question is specifically about a gender neutral version for aunt uncle and this question does not mention gender.

Comment: English is particularly poor in the *words for relatives* department.

Comment: If you need to be really specific, "My Mother's older brother, and his family" or "My uncle Don and his family" is as close as you'll get.

Comment: *I had family visiting and I took them on a tour of the city*.  Do you see, "family" is different from "my family"?  "My family would be parents, siblings, spouse, children.  "Family" is not quite as closely related.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Short Answer

No.

---

### Long Answer

There isn't actually any suitable idiomatic word/phrase  that's pretty common and casual and can be used in day-to-day conversations and writings. None of the other answers address this. Your context gives the impression that it's a normal piece of writing.  *Second-degree relatives*, *extended family*, whatever you say— they're technical terms and don't even specify that it's your *aunt, uncle, and cousins* and **not** your *grandparents*. Most people will not get you easily and it'll probably make you sound awkward or nerdy.

The word you want is just too too specific. Just say it—my *aunt, uncle, and cousins*. What's wrong with that? It doesn't do to be lazy and sloppy in writing.

In fact, people will like hearing more about them. Describe them better if you can. It'll give you a topic to talk on, triggering conversations. Short, concise, to-the-point writing is for academia.

> **X:** You know, my aunt, uncle, and my cousins came to see me yesterday. I toured around the city with them.
> **Y:** Oh, cool! It must have been exciting. Did you have fun?
> **X:** Yes, my cousins are such cuties. Amanda's 5 and she...

---

#### On a second note,

you might consider — ***my aunt and her family*** or ***my aunt's family***. Personally, I like the former better:

> Today I toured around the city with **my aunt and her family** who came to visit me.

*An aunt* sounds odd to me. You don't need to hint that you have more aunts and it's just one of them. It's *your* aunt and not somebody else's — that's more important to focus on.

Alternately, if your uncle's the direct relative and your aunt his wife, then say "***my uncle's family***" instead.

Comment: Hard-hitting answer @ Soha Farhin Pine which makes the pertinent point that for many single-word requests there is no answer. Why people are reluctant to say so if it is true? Though I saw this answer only today (so late) I am glad that you have [put the bell on the cat](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=put+the+bell+on+the+cat), cut the [Gordian knot](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordian_Knot) and basically created a **new type of answer for single-word-requests**. It makes me feel so proud of you. Will @PinkyTune be writing questions and answers here?

Answer (score 17):

It's still somewhat ambiguous, but

> "Extended Family"

might be a better phrase, or possibly

> "Some of my Extended Family"

to indicate it's not all of them.

Edit: To improve this answer I'm also including some dictionary entries

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/extended-family

> 2. (loosely) one's family conceived of as including aunts, uncles, cousins, in-laws, and sometimes close friends and colleagues.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/extended-family

> An extended family is a family group that includes relatives such as uncles, aunts, and grandparents, as well as parents, children, and brothers and sisters.

Comment: I would take "extended family" to refer to cases of re-marriage or possibly family for whom the connection to you is via a sibling's spouse. In other words, no blood relation. Aunts and uncles and cousins are just plain "family".

Comment: @CCTO It might be regional (NorthEast US) then. I've only ever heard "Extended Family" to refer to relatives that are not your parents/siblings (who would collectively be referred to as your "immediate family")

Comment: This depends if the aunt/uncle is by marriage or blood. I would not call them "extended" if they are blood relatives, only if they are by marriage. And even then "extended family" would refer to *everyone* on my partner's side of the family which could be dozens of families.

Answer (score 10):

A better expressions would be "My aunt/uncle and her/his family" which implies my aunt or uncle and their immediate family. You could use "mother's family" or "father's family", although this could refer to their parent, grandparents etc..

Edit: I use this myself - when my wife's brother comes to England from the US with his wife and children, I say that "We spent the day with my brother-in-law and his family".

Answer (score 0):

If the aunt is your blood relative of your father, then, "My father's sister's family", gets us to four words and reduces ambiguity by turning the sentence into a directed graph of your family tree. If you really want short, `"With Kin."` is about as short as you can get, but you compromise on precision.

Technically your aunt is your first cousin-once-removed, so "With cousins" is a tie for short, (in words if not letters) but again fails on the ambiguity front.

Its up to you to balance precision and accuracy, depending on your audience.